# componentDidUpdate not firing after each render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm tracking when `componentDidUpdate` and `render` are firing with log statements.

**The log statements in `componentDidUpdate` do not fire after `render`. I have used breakpoints to confirm this isn't a timing issue.**

I'm using "render props" to wrap the component in question. My code (stripped down) is below. This is the output of the logging. Sometimes I'll get `componentDidUpdate` to fire, but inconsistently and it's never the final thing, a `RENDER` always shows up in my logs last, never `UPDATE`.

As I understand it `componentDidUpdate` should fire even if the update does not modify the DOM (though the renders here *do* update the DOM.) I've tried `React@16.11.x` and `React@16.12.x` with identical results.

[image]

```js
class MyWrapper extends React.PureComponent {

  render() {
  const { buttonDefinitions } = this.props;
    return (
      <InfoProvider
        render={infoProps => {
          return (
            <MyMenu
              {...{ buttonDefinitions, infoProps }}
            />
          );
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

```js
class MyMenu extends React.Component {
  componentDidUpdate() {
    log.warn('UPDATE');
  }

  render() {
    log.warn('RENDER');
    const { buttonDefinitions } = this.props;
    return (
      <MenuWrapper>
        {buttonDefinitions.map(buttonDef => (
          <MyButton {...buttonDef} />
        ))}
      </MenuWrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `componentDidUpdate()` will not be called when `shouldComponentUpdate()` returns false.

Comment: Thanks @Kars, but `shouldComponentUpdate` is not in use and `render` IS called. Although we're not using it, if `shouldComponentUpdate` did return false, `render` would not be called.

Comment: Could you add a `componentDidMount` to `MyMenu` and make sure it is not being unmounted and mounted again? If that's the case, `InfoProvider` might be causing that, but I can't tell without actually seeing more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

As per [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html), if you are using render props with React pure component, then shallow prop comparison will always return false for new props. In this case, for each render it will generate a new value for the render prop. As new props getting created & not updating previous one it won't call componentDidUpdate.